# Debugging in visual studio code doesn´t work

Tags: c, visual-studio

I can't debug in visual studio code. I have tried to debug a program written in C, but the debugger doesn't  stop at the breakpoints that I set. I am using the latest version. The funny part of all this is that it worked for me before. Sorry for my English, I' m still learning.

Comment: Watch the Output window in VS for several lines "*loaded <module-name>. Symbols loaded.*". If you don't see the "*symbols loaded*" part check your settings under Tools / Options / Debugging / Symbols.

Comment: Are you using MingW GCC?

Comment: Hoang Nam I don't understand what you mean when you say to use text editor. dxiv  I did what you said and it didn't work. Lucas: Yes, I am using MingW gcc. Thanks for answering. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What did you do between "[it worked] before" and now? Don't tell us you did nothing. As you see, there must be something.

Comment: I did not do anything. I didn't even modify the config file. At one point today, the program started working again, but again it stopped working.